# MySQL returns a date format different that it has been setted

Tags: mysql

i have a MySQL's db with 2 DATE columns and when i add a registry the date is saved like this 2018/07/30. The problem is that when i make a get call to the db the value comes like this"2018-07-30T03:00:00.000Z"

I do not need the time part, and i think that the DATE type i have set to the column should not return this kind of value.

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
"SELECT * FROM patrones WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bd_fRecepcion, '%Y-%m-%d') WHERE bd_SI = 'Si' "
```

How could i do to get retuned the date part only?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't have two `WHERE` clauses in a query.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a registry"?

Comment: It sounds like you're using a tool that displays `DATE` columns as `DATETIME`, and it's converting from the database's timezone, so it's off by 3 hours.

Comment: You can use `DATE_FORMAT()` to control how the column is displayed.

Comment: registry = new data

Comment: You mean a row?

Comment: I have tried doing the get request with and API Client added to Chrome and with and API writting by me with NODE. In both cases the result is the same

Comment: yes i mean a  row

Comment: I think PHP will return a `DATE` as just `2018-07-30`, it won't add atime.

Comment: Javascript is probably converting it to a `Date` object. Javascript `Date` includes the time, there's no way to create a `Date` with no time in it.

Comment: understood, probably that is the problem, i will investigate how to extract only the date part of the date object. thank you

Comment: GIGO?  MySQL never generates "...T03:00:00.000Z"; perhaps you stored that into a VARCHAR?